# Combining 3 mysql queries into 1

Tags: php, mysql

I need to query two new table $res_info and $res_text... how can I combine all 3 queries into one. The first query $res grabs everything include the unique field m_id which is used in the two other tables. can this be done with a `UNION`?

```
$res = @mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(m_lld,'%m/%d/%y') 
                    AS m_lld_formatted 
                    FROM social_members
                    WHERE m_user='$en[user]'");

if (@mysql_num_rows($res) == 0) call404();
$line = @mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
foreach ($line as $key => $value) 
        $en['m'.$key] = str_replace("\n",'<br/>',stripslashes($value));

$res_info = mysql_query("SELECT *, 
                            FROM social_meminfo 
                            WHERE m_id = '".$en['mm_id']."'");
$res_text = mysql_query("SELECT *, 
                            FROM social_memtext 
                            WHERE m_id = '".$en['mm_id']."'");
```

Comment: How are the relations between the tables? All one-on-one?

Comment: Can you not use a simple join on 3 tables on your key `m_id`?

Comment: @anubhava query 1 needs to use m_user before it can get m_id ... how would I go about joining them?

Comment: @WesleyvanOpdorp all 3 tables have the m_id field in common

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments I think you are looking for one `OUTER JOIN` and another `INNER JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT sm.*, DATE_FORMAT(sm.m_lld,'%m/%d/%y') AS m_lld_formatted 
FROM social_members sm
LEFT OUTER JOIN social_memtext smt ON (sm.m_id = smt.m_id)
JOIN social_meminfo smi ON (sm.m_id = smi.m_id)
WHERE sm.m_user = "$en['user']"
```

`LEFT OUTER JOIN` will take care of situation when table `social_memtext` does have matching entries.

Comment: is LEFT OUTER JOIN better than a LEFT JOIN for performance if a lot of profiles are being accessed?

Comment: I used `LEFT OUTER JOIN` because you wrote in 1 of the comments that table social_memtex may not have any matching entries.

Answer (score 1):

```
//use mysql_real_escape_string for your $en['User']
SELECT sm.*, DATE_FORMAT(sm.m_lld,'%m/%d/%y') 
                    AS m_lld_formatted 
                    FROM social_members sm
                    JOIN social_meminfo smi ON(smi.m_id = sm.m_id)
                    JOIN social_memtext smt ON(smt.m_id = sm.m_id)
                    WHERE sm.m_user = "$en['user']"
```

Comment: one problem, social_memtext might have no entries so when `if (@mysql_num_rows($res) == 0) call404();` runs it throws and error404 how do I sent it to not error if `smt` is empty?

Comment: If you want to return results even if `social_memtext` has no entries, you can change that `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` and any columns from that table simply have `NULL` values.